# Regex match anything but (0/\d+)

Tags: regex

How do I match anything but `(0/\d+)` :

```
aaa 0/1 ddd
fff 0/111 fff
38383 0/24 39303 .. 303
```

In this example I'd like to match everything but:

```
0/1
0/111
0/24
```

The end goal is to clean a text file and leave only these strings in it:

```
0/1
0/111
0/24
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*\(0\/[0-9]\+\).*/\1/g' input.txt
```

**Explanation:**

The above command matches a `0` followed by a forward slash and one ore more following numbers into capturing group `1`. Everything else `.*` before and after the match is thrown away. `g` means that `sed` applies the replacement as many times as the pattern matches and not only once.

**Output:**

```
0/1 
0/111 
0/24
```

Comment: I need the exact opposite.

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*(\b0\/\d+\b).*$
```

Try this.Replace by `$1` or `\1`.See demo.use `Multiline mode`

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/16

Comment: Can this be modified to work with more than one match per line and ignoring spaces, eg: `fff0/111fff0/111fff`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove anything, just matching would be fine.

```
grep -o '0/[0-9]\+' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'fff0/111fff0/111fff' | grep -o '0/[0-9]\+'
0/111
0/111
```